# Text Overlaps when JTextArea background is set to transparent

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to create a transparent JTextArea but the updated text  overlaps with the previous one.

I tried using scrollpane, borderlayout and setOpaque(false) method of TextArea but none of them worked.

[image]
**Transparent Background - >**
[image]

Here is the code

```
public class PanelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PanelTest test = new PanelTest();
        test.createUI();
    }

    public void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel Test");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));


        JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea("");
        jTextArea.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        jTextArea.setRows(12);
        jTextArea.setColumns(7);

        
        frame.add(jTextArea);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while (true) {
                    
                    String s = execute("cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq");
                    System.out.println(s.length());
                    jTextArea.setText(s);
        
                    try {
                        this.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)` in order to make the `JTextArea` transparent. Use `setOpaque(false)` instead.

Also, do not make updates to components outside of event dispatch thread. When you want to run a "heavy/long" task you should use a `SwingWorker` and publish updates to the UI thread (called Event dispatch thread) by using `publish` method.  I recommend you to read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in order to understand how things should work in a Swing environment when it comes to threading.

A full example that reads terminal's output when executing `java -version`. Notice the `process.getErrorStream`. `java -version` command writes to error stream. You might want to change that.

```
public class PanelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            PanelTest test = new PanelTest();
            test.createUI();
        });
    }

    public void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea("");
        jTextArea.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea.setOpaque(false);
        jTextArea.setRows(12);
        jTextArea.setColumns(7);

        frame.add(jTextArea);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        SwingWorker<Void, String> terminalReader = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                while (true) {
                    String s = executeTerminalCommand("java -version");
                    publish(s);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                if (!chunks.isEmpty()) {
                    String text = chunks.get(0);
                    jTextArea.setText("");
                    jTextArea.setText(text);
                    jTextArea.repaint();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        terminalReader.execute();
    }

    private static String executeTerminalCommand(String command) throws IOException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        return readInputStreamAsString(process.getErrorStream());
    }

    public static String readInputStreamAsString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            int result = bis.read();
            while (result != -1) {
                byte b = (byte) result;
                buf.write(b);
                result = bis.read();
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did run your code and found the same thing. Do you think my desktop environment has anything to do with this? I'm currently on GNOME 3.36.4. Can you tell me on which environment your code worked?

Comment: @jspphani I tested in Windows 7. Did you test my example as is, or you tried to adjust it to your needs?

Comment: I tested it as is and also modified to my cause, none of them worked. Maybe it's gnome's doing